# Next.js multidat/form-data parsing using formidable

Tags: javascript, next.js, multipartform-data

I am trying to build a next.js app that takes in a multipart/form-data to then receive it from an endpoint that parses the formdata into name,address,and file.

I tried using Formidable to parse the formdata object, but have been struggling to get it working. The fields and file are all returning `{} {}`. (empty). Are there any suggestions as to how to parse the form data?

```js
export default function supplier(req, res) {
  if (req.method == 'POST') {
    //console.log("req: \n",req);
    console.log("req body: \n",req.body);
    //console.log("req.file: \n",req.headers);
    //console.log("req.address: \n",req.body.address);
    
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    //console.log("form: \n",form);
    //const form = new multiparty.Form();
    let FormResp = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      form.parse(req, (err, fields, files)=>{
          console.log("fields: ",fields);
          console.log("files: ",files);
          //await saveFile(files.file);
          //await saveDB();
          return res.status(201).send("");
      });
    });
  } else {
    // Handle any other HTTP method
    return res.status(405).json({ error: `Method '${req.method}' Not Allowed` });
  }
```

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formdata = new FormData();
    const json = JSON.stringify({"name":event.target.name.value, "address":event.target.address.value, "file": createObjectURL})
    
    formdata.append("file", image);
    formdata.append("name", event.target.name.value);
    formdata.append("address", event.target.address.value);
    console.log("formdata: \n", formdata);

    //var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //request.open("POST", "/api/supplier");
    //request.send(formData:body);

    const response = await fetch("/api/supplier",{method: 'POST', body: formdata, "content-type":"multipart/form-data"});

    //const result = await response.json()
    //console.log(result)
    
  };

------WebKitFormBoundaryiu8apU5i3hWyORTY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

Hello
------WebKitFormBoundaryiu8apU5i3hWyORTY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="address"

addressssssssss
------WebKitFormBoundaryiu8apU5i3hWyORTY--

req body: 
 ------WebKitFormBoundary92WJpSOKb0mEfOAH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="attachment.svg"
Content-Type: image/svg+xml

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 48 48" viewBox="0 0 48 48"><path d="M35.5,34V16c0-0.83-0.67-1.5-1.5-1.5s-1.5,0.67-1.5,1.5v18c0,4.69-3.81,8.5-8.5,8.5s-8.5-3.81-8.5-8.5V11
        c0-3.03,2.47-5.5,5.5-5.5s5.5,2.47,5.5,5.5v21.5c0,1.38-1.12,2.5-2.5,2.5s-2.5-1.12-2.5-2.5V13c0-0.83-0.67-1.5-1.5-1.5
        s-1.5,0.67-1.5,1.5v19.5c0,3.03,2.47,5.5,5.5,5.5s5.5-2.47,5.5-5.5V11c0-4.69-3.81-8.5-8.5-8.5s-8.5,3.81-8.5,8.5v23
        c0,6.34,5.16,11.5,11.5,11.5S35.5,40.34,35.5,34z"/></svg>
------WebKitFormBoundary92WJpSOKb0mEfOAH
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `multipart/form-data` in your title ?

A workaround for using formidable in Next.js is to disable the built-in body parser. This can be done by exporting a config object from your API route and setting api.bodyParser to false. This will leave the request stream untouched so that formidable can parse it.

Just add the following lines:

```
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
}

export default async function yourRoute(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this might be a bit late. But don't try to return res inside Promise directly. First resolve the promise and from the output it gives we can then send the response

```
export default function supplier(req, res) {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    // Handle any other HTTP method
    res.status(405).json({ error: `Method '${req.method}' Not Allowed` });
    return;
  }
    
  let FormResp = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    const form = formidable();
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files)=>{
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve({ fields, files });
    });
  });

  const { fields } = FormResp;
  console.log(fields);
}
```